# Multiple functions to establish a fallback value for a property until not null

Tags: c#, null, lambda, unity3d

I have a property (called "Head") that can be set externally. When "Head" is not set, it uses Unity3D's `MonoBehaviour` functions to try to find the best value for "Head". I started with a nested `if`, but the nesting was starting to get out of hand.

```
if (Head == null)
{
    Head = this.GetComponent<Camera>();

    if (Head == null)
    {
        Head = this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();

        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = Camera.main;
        }
    }
}
```

So I developed a loop:

```
System.Func<Camera>[] fallbacks = new System.Func<Camera>[]
{
    () => this.GetComponent<Camera>(),
    () => this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>(),
    () => Camera.main,
};

foreach (var fallback in fallbacks)
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
        break;
    }
    Head = fallback();
}
```

Would this create too much lambda overhead? Do you think the lambdas even increases readability? Is there a more elegant way to handle multiple fallbacks?

**Edit:**

[RobH](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22816/robh) helped me discover the [Null coalescing doesn't work with Unity3D components](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/null-coalescing-doesnt-work-with-components.92156/).
[RobH](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/22816/robh)'s extension method workaround worked great with some tweaking. I had to enforce that comparison had to be done through UnityEngine.Object.

```
public static T IfNullThen<T>(this T obj, Func<T> factory) where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    return obj != null ? obj : factory();
}
```

With that extension method my code is now just

```
Head = Head
    .IfNullThen(() => this.GetComponent<Camera>())
    .IfNullThen(() => this.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>())
    .IfNullThen(() => Camera.main);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a textbook case for the null coalescing operator `??`

```
Head = GetComponent<Camera>() ?? GetComponentInChildren<Camera>() ?? Camera.main;
```

You also (probably) don't need to prefix with `this`

Edit:

If the null coalescing operator doesn't work (which is a massive shame) why not create an extension method?

```
public static T IfNullThen<T>(this T obj, Func<T> factory) where T : class
{
    return obj != null ? obj : factory();
    // or
    // return obj == null ? factory() : obj;
}
```

then you can do:

```
Head = GetComponent<Camera>().IfNullThen(GetComponentInChildren<Camera>).IfNullThen(() => Camera.main);
```

Unfortunately I'm on my mac so I don't have a compiler but I *think* it should work :)

Comment: `System` namespace qualifier to `System.Func<T>` is probably also redundant ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm so used to ReSharper fixing that sort of thing that I don't look for them anymore! :)

Comment: This is brilliant and should of totally worked. I was racking my brain why it wasn't. Unity3D has issues with null coalesing. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/null-coalescing-doesnt-work-with-components.92156/

Comment: @ShawnFeatherly - does my edit make sense/work?

Comment: @RobH, worked great and much more readable. Thanks! Had to do some tweaks. I updated above with what I had to change.

Comment: @ShawnFeatherly - Ah yes. Need to use UnityEngine.Object to pick up on the custom `==` implementation. Glad it helped.